# Getting the nearest values to the left in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the daily temperatures of 4 countries as below:

| Day | GB | US | AU | CA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 32 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 23 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 34 |  |  |  |
| 5 | 23 | 34 |  |  |
| 6 | 45 | 34 |  |  |
| 7 | 34 | 23 |  |  |
| 8 | 34 | 33 |  |  |
| 9 | 34 | 45 | 44 | 12 |
| 10 | 23 | 23 | 23 | 23 |
| 11 |  | 34 | 23 | 45 |
| 12 |  | 12 | 23 | 44 |
| 13 |  | 34 | 66 | 53 |
| 14 |  | 34 | 34 | 33 |
| 15 |  | 43 | 34 | 22 |
| 16 |  | 45 | 56 | 34 |
| 17 |  |  | 34 | 32 |
| 18 |  |  | 22 | 12 |
| 19 |  |  |  | 12 |
| 20 |  |  |  | 12 |

I am trying to create a function that will return the nearest value to the left for any given day plus an offset. In other words, if you were to draw a hypothetical horizontal line from the left to the right for each row (where `offset=0`) then then the value returned should be the one that would be encountered first. i.e. an `offset=1` will just return the 2nd intersection, and `offset=2` will return the 3rd and so on.

```
def nearest(offset=0):
    #return df
```

so that for example:

`nearest(0)` will output:

| Day | Temp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 |
| 2 | 32 |
| 3 | 23 |
| 4 | 34 |
| 5 | 23 |
| 6 | 45 |
| 7 | 34 |
| 8 | 34 |
| 9 | 34 |
| 10 | 23 |
| 11 | 34 |
| 12 | 12 |
| 13 | 34 |
| 14 | 34 |
| 15 | 43 |
| 16 | 45 |
| 17 | 34 |
| 18 | 22 |
| 19 | 34 |
| 20 | 12 |

and `nearest(1)`:

| Day | Temp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | 34 |
| 6 | 34 |
| 7 | 23 |
| 8 | 33 |
| 9 | 45 |
| 10 | 23 |
| 11 | 23 |
| 12 | 23 |
| 13 | 66 |
| 14 | 34 |
| 15 | 34 |
| 16 | 56 |
| 17 | 32 |
| 18 | 12 |
| 19 |  |
| 20 |  |

Reality is that I have about 10 countries which are all staggered like the first table above and offset value can be as high as 9!

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the empty cells are `NaN`s:

```py
def nearest(df, offset=0):
    x = df.loc[:, "GB":].apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isna)[offset], axis=1)
    return x


print(nearest(df, 1))
```

Prints:

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4     34.0
5     34.0
6     23.0
7     33.0
8     45.0
9     23.0
10    23.0
11    23.0
12    66.0
13    34.0
14    34.0
15    56.0
16    32.0
17    12.0
18     NaN
19     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: many thanks. is there a faster way with numpy to vectorize or use numbas?